# how to add to add socket.io subscribers in node.js without rerunning setup code

Tags: node.js, twitter, socket.io

*Now edited with solution*

I'm writing a web page, backed by Node and Express, which uses the twitter streaming API to plot the location of tweets containing a given word onto a Google map. The page connects to the server and places each tweet with location that the server emits onto the map.

the node js application is this. twitFactory just gives me a twitter object from the Twitter npm module with my various connection strings.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var twitFactory = require('./lib/twitFactory');
var twit = twitFactory.twit();

var searchTerm = process.argv[2];
var locations = '-180,-90,180,90';
server.listen(3000);

app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    twit.stream('filter', {locations: locations}, function (stream) {
        stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
            if (tweet.text && tweet.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                if (tweet.text && tweet.coordinates && tweet.coordinates.coordinates && tweet.coordinates.type === 'Point') {
                    socket.emit('tweet', { text: tweet.text, lon: tweet.coordinates.coordinates[0], lat: tweet.coordinates.coordinates[1] });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have this working for a single web client, which is fine for my development environment, but I want to avoid re-initialising the Twitter connection inside the on connection event every time a new client connects, or I would quickly hit my API call limit.

I think I want to define the twitter stream separately, and then add new connections to the socket's subscribers, but can't work out how to code this, without the nested structure you see above.

(I realise that it's very inefficient to get all tweets with location then filter by content, but very few tweets have location attached, and the API does not currently let you specify location AND search term, it gives you all tweets with either.)

UPDATE:

I found a solution which was to use a different Twitter Node module which allows the stream object and events to be declared separately. it's twit (as opposed to twitter) in npm. the code now looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var logger = require('./lib/logger');
var twitFactory = require('./lib/twitFactory');
var searchTerm = process.argv[2];
var locations = ['-180','-90','180','90'];

var twit = twitFactory.twit();
var tweetStream = twit.stream('statuses/filter', {locations: locations});

server.listen(3000);

app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('new connection');
    tweetStream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {    
        if (tweet.text && tweet.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) != -1) {    
            if (tweet.text && tweet.coordinates && tweet.coordinates.coordinates && tweet.coordinates.type === 'Point') {
                socket.emit('tweet', { text: tweet.text, lon: tweet.coordinates.coordinates[0], lat: tweet.coordinates.coordinates[1] });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just store a flag for whether you've already initialized the twitter stream or not and then in the `connection` handler, you just check if that flag is set or not?

Comment: thanks for the response. the problem with that approach is that the code which responds to the stream data events and sends the socket.emit call is nested inside the twitter stream initialisation. so if I conditionally run the code block starting with the stream init then only the first client gets the event. any subsequent connections get no events broadcast their way.

Comment: You shouldn't be just doing `socket.emit()` because that only sends the results to one user.  I'd suggest you put each connected user into a chat room when they connect (just a way of keeping track of a group of sockets and easily broadcasting to that group) and then you can easily broadcast the tweets to everyone in a given chatroom.  The socket.io doc shows how to make simple chatrooms work.

Comment: I've been following the socket.io chatroom example. socket.emit() will send to all connected clients. socket.broadcast.emit() sends to all except the originator of a message. it's all working fine now, thanks :)